# Test Automation Capture Network Data on Mobile Device

Tags: java, android, selenium, sdk, appium

Let me share my end to end flow with you which i am trying to automate.

I have developed Automation test suite using Java,Selenium and Appium. 
It does the following:

1. Open Chrome Browser on Mobile Device
2. Once browser is opened browse URL
3. On browser HTML5 Media player is launched having our Video SDK
4. Automation suite monitors video duration, captures Ad details (Like Ads in YouTube videos)
5. Monitor & Capture network calls invoked by Video SDK
6. Read data from network calls

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use browsermob proxy jar. It will help you to read the network tab calls.

This below link is enough notes.

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example

Comment: The BrowserMob proxy is not being maintained. I'd suggest that same rough code example, but using the BrowserUp proxy fork: https://github.com/browserup/browserup-proxy